# Check substring with spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract some data with spaces from a string. Here is my code:

```
if (somestring.contains("LOOP with spaces")) {
    i++;
}
```

Is there a regular expression to extract this: I tried this but did not work

```
somestring.contains("LOOP\swith\s spaces"))
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?  What's wrong with just finding the string?

Comment: returns nothing is i use ("LOOP with spaces")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matches` instead if you want to use a regular expression as an argument:

`if (somestring.matches(".*LOOP\\swith\\sspaces.*")){`

Note that (1) `.*` means any number of any character and, (2) you need to *escape* the backslash in Java: `\\` is interpreted as `\`.

Comment: It did for me in Java. What is the string you're testing with?

Comment: @Bathsheba May be OP has multispaces and wants something like `.*LOOP\\s+with\\s+spaces.*`. Difficult to tell since the problem is not stated clearly.

Comment: the string that I am using is " INFO - LOOP with spaces : some other text goes in here on ever line "

Comment: @user3588388 So what do you want to do? Check if string contains `LOOP with spaces`? Or extract `LOOP with spaces` - what the point of extraction of constant string?

Comment: Because "LOOP" and "Loop" are not the same, maybe?

Comment: @user3588388 Change regex to `(?i).*LOOP\\swith\\sspaces.*`

Comment: Ok Marking this question as answered. Will need to start a new question as the string somethimg is being read from a file, and the regex is not working. Thanks guys